# What is the Reduce for a parallel_reduce in tbb?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda, tbb

[`parallel_reduce`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_reduce_func.htm) offers 2 interfaces, the one for the lambdas can be used like showed in the previous link

```
#include "tbb/parallel_reduce.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"

using namespace tbb;

float ParallelSum( float array[], size_t n ) {
    return parallel_reduce( 
        blocked_range<float*>( array, array+n ), 
        0.f, 
        [](const blocked_range<float*>& r, float init)->float {
            for( float* a=r.begin(); a!=r.end(); ++a ) 
                init += *a;
            return init;
        },
        []( float x, float y )->float { // what this lambda does ?
            return x+y;
        }
    );                    
}
```

the second lambda fits in the `const Reduction& reduction` signature, I'm studying this lambda trying to change the body or the values, but it does exactly nothing ( even if I put a `cout` inside, nothing happens ), looks like it's there for no reason at all.

What is the purpose of this `Reduction` ?
Has something to do with the `0f` ? For what I got that `0f` is a predicate used to detect what are the values that can be skipped, but I still can't figure out what that lambda does ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first lambda computes the expression over the range, giving a result for that range.

The second lambda combines the results from two range computations, giving a result for the combination of the two ranges.

The second lambda will only get called if the `parallel_reduce` breaks up the operation into multiple ranges.

Comment: this thing is explained on that page in other terms or I'm blind and I'm not able to see that on the page ?

Comment: It's all compressed into this sentence: "The functional form parallel_reduce(range,identity,func,reduction) performs a parallel reduction by applying func to subranges in range and reducing the results using binary operator reduction."

Comment: Well, that, and the table just after, where it says Func "Accumulate(s) result for subrange, starting with initial value x" and Reduction "Combine(s) results x and y."

Comment: Also, the `0.f` is, as stated on that page the "Left identity element for Func::operator()". In the example, `0` is the identity of addition (adding 0 does not change the result). _This provides a starting point for `func`_ - it's probably passed to the `init` parameter.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy : Thanks, I neglected to mention that.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy which means that if I pass `4f` it will add `4` to any float in the array and then add them together ?

Comment: @JoeZ ok, not completely crystal clear, but I assume that in this sentence the key part is `binary`, thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 : As far as Identity is concerned, I imagine it will have zero or more opportunities to affect the result in a given computation.  If you put something there that isn't actually a mathematical identity function for whatever reduction you're doing (0 for addition, 1 for multiplication, identity matrix...), you'll get an unpredictable result.  For example, 4.0f might do nothing to the result, add 4.0f to every value, anything in-between, or something I haven't even anticipated.

Comment: @user2485710 ehhh.... I wouldn't do that. There will not be a predictable result at all, because you don't know how the runtime will split up your subranges and how many times this `4.f` will be mixed into your result. The whole purpose is to provide a mathematical binary function and it's identity element. E.g:
(operation: +, identity: 0) or (operation: *, identity: 1)
It's a fundamental assumption of the library that you dont mess that up- `4.0` doesn't make sense there. To be _very_ specific it wants what's called a Monoid in mathematics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy ok, a question for both, in math terms an identity is well know for a type and an operation, why I should give an input where this input can be clearly deduced by the context of what I'm doing, what is the purpose of giving me that interface if the only reasonable thing to do is to put `0f` in there ( for the float case ).

Comment: @user2485710 The library can't possibly know what you're doing in that function. Like I said, if you do _addition_, the identity is `0`, if you do _multiplication_, the identity is `1`.

Comment: @user2485710 : `parallel_reduce` doesn't know if you're doing an add-reduce, multiply-reduce, xor-reduce, or-reduce, and-reduce etc.  It cannot deduce an appropriate identity value.  It's not a compiler.  It's just receiving lambda expressions or functors.

Comment: @JoeZ haha we're repeating each other, this is funny

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy :  :-D  Yep!

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy i forgot about the multiplication, and other possible operations, thanks for the reminder. Ok now things are clear, thanks to both of you :D .

Comment: Oh, and I almost forgot, max-reduce and min-reduce, both of which need opposite "identity" values.  (max needs the minimum representable value, while min needs the maximum representable value, to work over the entire range of possible inputs.)

Comment: Hmm... I wonder who downvoted?  I'm happy to hear your concern.

Comment: Slides 150 and 151 of http://parallelbook.com/sites/parallelbook.com/files/SC13_20131117_Intel_McCool_Robison_Reinders_Hebenstreit.pdf might help clarify where the 0 comes into play.